# how to create gmail dot trick generator in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to try making a Gmail dot trick generator, so adding the dot to the string randomly like `uname` becomes `u.name`, `u.n.ame`, `u.n.a.me`, etc

I've searched everywhere and tried but always failed :(
can somebody help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @NewToJS i try to convert algorithm php to js https://thebot.net/threads/gmail-dot-trick-algorithm-in-php.2486/ but :(

Comment: Why not look at [**thebot.net api gmail trick.js**](https://thebot.net/api/gmail/trick.js)

Comment: whoaa thnks info

Answer (score 2):

```
function choose(choices) {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
  return choices[index];
}

function dotit(email){
  var username = email.split("@")[0]
  var dotemail = ""
  for(i=0;i<username.length-1;i++){
    dotemail +=username[i]+choose(["", "."])
  }
  dotemail +=username[username.length-1]+"@gmail.com"
  return dotemail
}


console.log(dotit("someone@gmail.com"))
```